# Salesforce Live Agent EndChat api is not working

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, liveagent

I have Customized chat window and I need to connect with salesforce live agent so I integrated LiveAgent API of salesforce. For closing the chat I trigger end chat API I am getting 200 response but chat window is not closing.

```
endChat(userId: string){

        let objArr: User[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userCreden'));
        let len = objArr.length;
        let user: User;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (userId == objArr[i].userId) {
                user = objArr[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        let sessionIdRespParsed = user.sessresp;

        let live_agent_url = this.appConfig.getConfig().live_agent_server_url;
        this.httpClient.post<HttpResponse<string>>(live_agent_url + '/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChatEnd', {
            "reason":"client"
        }, {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION': '34',
                    'X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY': sessionIdRespParsed.affinityToken,
                    'X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY': sessionIdRespParsed.key,
                    'X-LIVEAGENT-SEQUENCE': '1'
                })
        }).subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log("response of Chat end  " + res);
            },
            err => {

            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to sfse, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include the relevant code (preferable, minimal reproducible code sample) and a clear description of the problem alongside any errors.

Comment: @Eduard i am new to StackExchange next time i will take care. :). You have solution of my error i am getting 200 response code but still chat is not closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you. But I had the same issue and it seems like simply deleting this header:

'X-LIVEAGENT-SEQUENCE': '1'

does the trick.